# MFMailComposeViewController is buggy on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I recently found out that MFMailComposeViewController behaves buggy when entering the recipient email, it causes a loop going in the view as shown in the GIF below: [Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7uru.gif)

My implementation of MFMailComposeViewController is pretty standard:

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
   let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
   mail.setSubject("Report an issue")
   mail.setMessageBody("", isHTML: true)
   present(mail, animated: true)
} else {
}
```

I have not been able to replicate this on iOS 14.6 but other users were able to replicate this behavior. They have iOS 14.3 and 14.4 on iPhone X. I think it has something to do with the iOS version or the specific iPhone model.

Is there any way I can use the simulator to debug MFMailComposeViewController functionality? Even removing canSendMail(), I can't seem to make it works with the simulator.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide code as text in a `code block` rather that adding images.